# Run startActivity/startService by inspecting an intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a setup where a BroadcastReceiver receives an intent that could either be intended to launch a service or an activity. Is there someway I can inspect the intent and decide whether to startActivity or startService with it? The service intents will be explicit and will have been initialized with the name of the service.

Comment: decide depending on what? Are you inspecting your own `Intent` or a system one? You can check the component via `getComponent` for explicit intents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the code which launches the Intent, you can use `putExtra()` to add a variable to your Intent, which you later check in your BroadcastReceiver `onReceive()` method. Something like:

```
//Intent to start an Activity
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);   
String start = "Activity";
i.putExtra("from", start);

//Intent to start a Service
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);   
String start = "Service";
i.putExtra("from", start);
```

So, in your `onReceive()` method, you need to check the value of the string and thereby to determine the origin and purpose of the intent:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String start = intent.getStringExtra("from");
    switch(start){
        case "Activity":
        //Start activity
        break;

        case "Service":
        //Start service
        break;
    }
}
```